# adding a counting colum to a numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1d numpy array `ans`, i.e.:

```
ans=[8,5,9,2,4]
```

I want to convert it into a 2d array like:

```
ans=
{[1,8],  
[2,5],       
[3,9],  
[4,2],  
[5,4]}
```

the first column is in sequence:

```
[1,2,3......500,501..]
```

How to do this in python?

Comment: How is `ans` 2d? Why do you post it as a python list, but say it's an array? Why is you desired ouput a python set?

Comment: OP might be used to C. But generally you are right an array needs to be a continous memory allocation, which is not necessary the case in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are actually working with numpy, and your question is just sloppy, here's one way with `numpy.vstack`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> right = np.array([8,5,9,2,4])
>>> np.vstack([np.arange(1, len(right) + 1), right]).T
array([[1, 8],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 9],
       [4, 2],
       [5, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very neat solution but if you have both the numpy arrays you could use `insert` and `reshape` to create your 2D array:

```
array_1 = np.array([8,5,9,2,4,5])
array_2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
array = np.insert(array_2, array_2, array_1)
array = np.reshape(array, (-1,2))
print array

[[1 8]
 [2 5]
 [3 9]
 [4 2]
 [5 4]
 [6 5]]

print type(array)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) along the second axis:

```
>>> ans = np.array([8, 5, 9, 2, 4])
>>> np.stack((np.arange(1, len(ans) + 1), ans), axis=1)
array([[1, 8],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 9],
       [4, 2],
       [5, 4]])
```